# C# problem with Packing the supporting files with EXE, while publishing the project

Tags: c#, .net

I am using visual studio 2005, (.net version is 2.0+) to create a windows application. The functionality of the project is matching with the ideal design, there is just one problem in publishing the project.

I use MouseHover method to change the picture(image) used in intention to make attractive UI, when I hover the mouse pointer over the picture .. some other pic is loaded in-place of it .. and in mouseleave method the same picture is retained back.

Now the problem is while debugging this functionality works properly,
But when published, and used, the window won't load the image (as the **installed folder doesn't contain these images**) .. How to bind the supporting files like images, text files and any other files like xml with EXE??

 I mean is there any ideal way to publish the project??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project, ensure that the images are set to `Copy Always` or `Copy if Newer` on the `Copy To Output Folder` property (F4).

That should ensure that when doing an XCopy deploy the images will be in the right folder (you will proabably need to change the logic for finding the image paths, so the application finds them in the right directory).

Comment: @Oded, thanks for the valuable response and you time to share the knowledge .. I will try to locate those properties in my SDK, :)

btw, while debugging, I copy the relevant files in DEBUG folder so .. the file path would be simple and the **filename itself** ..

Comment: @Oded, sorry but files are not visible directly in SDK, but they are called(used) in code (**using pictureBox**).. I can overwrite the properties of the visible project files like Resx, designer.cs etc but can't edit this settings, Could you please let me know .. how can I do it?

Comment: @infant programmer - I assumed the images were included in the project. If you click on an image then `F4`, you should be able to see the property.

Comment: @Oded, yup, I was lagging behind :P .. I clicked on **view all files** then **selected** each image files from Debug folder then **added to the project**, then could change the property :)) its done thumbs up :)) thanks a ton :)

Comment: @infant programmer - Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using deployment project that will generate .MSI for your application, just right click on the project, click add files and then pick the images from your project directory.

Those files will be (by default) be deployed into the application target directory, and your end-user app will be able to access it.

Comment: Glad to see your easy way to hack this problem :) thanks for your valuable suggestion, I surely go head and try it out :) regards.

Comment: Just had to follow one more procedure to Change the property "COPY ALWAYS" :) (as suggested by "ODED") thanks a million for ur precious time and answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can package them as Embedded Resources.

To embed them, make sure that when the resources are selected in the Solution Explorer that the 'Build Action' in the Properties window is set to 'Embedded Resource'.

Here is an example with sample project on how to embed images : [How to use embedded resources in .Net](http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=83574)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable response and your knowledge :) I will sure go for it. :) regards.